# Unable to add apache qpid nuget package to c# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, qpid

I am new to apche qpid. I have tried adding nuget package for the same but it is failing and getting this following error in package manager:
"Failed to add reference to boost_chrono-vc120-mt-gd"

Answer (score 1):

What is the source for the package? Complaints about boost indicate that this is an old binding that uses Apache Qpid Cpp libraries underneath a .NET binding. This scheme has not been maintained. A better .NET solution is available at https://github.com/Azure/amqpdotnet